# flutter firebase auth: provider linked user has single dash as email

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I noticed this problem using `firebase_ui_auth` for flutter. But I'm not sure if this is by design or a bug:

I'm using firebase to authenticate users in my app and also allow them to register via a provider (Google and Apple). For a handful of users using **Apple Sign In**, I noticed that their email is being presented as a single dash. I assume this means, that their mail is `null`. For the vast majority of users using the provider sign-in method, though, this is not the case:

[image: see proof here]

The way I'm doing sign up in my app is as simple as it gets. I add all desired providers like written in the documentation in my main.dart like this

```
FirebaseUIAuth.configureProviders([
    EmailAuthProvider(),
    GoogleProvider(clientId: googleClientId, iOSPreferPlist: true),
    AppleProvider(),
  ]);
```

and then use the default `SignInScreen()` made by `firebase_ui_auth`.

I also noticed in the documentation, that the `AppleProvider()` uses the email scope by default, so I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here...

Does anybody know what's going on?